# How to display confirmation message when a user clicks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'm having issue trying to display a confirmation message when a checkbox is clicked. The confirmation box appears but doesn't perform any type of action such as displaying the text within the textbox when the user confirms OK. Any advice would do. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code.

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" 
                  OnClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you?'))return false;" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "blah";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a check box is not like a button. There is no OnClientClick for a check box.

However, you CAN use OnClick.

Also, the code stub (code behind) you have does NOT run like a button click UNLESS you set AutoPostback = true.

However, you can do it this way:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  
    OnClick="if (!confirm('really do this')) {return false;}" 
AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

You have to use the !not, and exit from the JavaScript routine, or you MUST LET the JS code continue, since it will do a post back for you. So, the above code spit out by asp.net becomes this:

```
<input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" 
  checked="checked" 
  onclick="if (!confirm('really do this')) {return false;};
  setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'CheckBox1\',\'\')', 0)">
```

So, we HAVE to let the js code "continue if we want ok, but if we don't confirm, then we MUST do a return false and exit the js code stub else the post back will in fact run regardless of returning true or false.  If fact even if we return true, then the stub exits and the following postback code never will run. So a return with either value still bails out of the generated code stub.

So the check box does NOT support the standard for most buttons in that you use js to return true, or false and thus as a result the post back does not occur.

We can't use say return confirm('Please hit ok') like we can for a button, since if we "return" a value then the post-back code that follows never runs.

So, for a button, the OnClientClick() return value (true/false) is tested for you, and that determines if the button post back will fire. Not so with a check box, and no OnClientClick is defined or supported. But as you can see above we can trick the page processor into working - since it simply appends it own post back code to what we stuff into OnClick.

But, a check box is different, and it does not really support OnClientClick. But if you shove code into OnClick(), then you can see the final rendered output. We thus LET the continue contine to run the postback if we confirm, but bail out (return false) if you don't confirm and the post back code that follows simply does not run.